# How to concatenate string and put it to buttons C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm currently working on a puzzle word game and kind of having a hard time implementing an **endless mode**

Here's an image for your reference

[image]

The one that is encircled in blue the code for that is this

```
textComp.text = "";

rowsToReadFrom[0] = indexx;
textArray = myTextAsset.text.Split('\n').ToList();
textComp.text += textArray[rowsToReadFrom[0]] + "\n";

indexx += 1;
```

And the one that is encircled in red is the one that I wanted and the code for that is this

```
char[] chars = words[index].GetString().ToCharArray();
        foreach (char c in chars)
        {
            testObject clone = Instantiate(prefab.gameObject).GetComponent<testObject>();
            clone.transform.SetParent(container);

            charObjects.Add(clone.Init(c));
        }
```

Could someone please point me out what should I do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's divide the problem in sub-problems and solve:

To `concatenate` `string` use `+` operator , it concatenates `string`*(s)* - **First one solved**

To put it into buttons get `length` of that `string`, now dynamically generate `Button`*(s)* same to the length of that `string` and position them one after one.

[Get character at *n*-th position using str[n], indexing from 0.]

Set text of the `Button`. - **Second problem solved**.

[This](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Button.html) will help creating `Button`.

Change `text` of a `Button` using `GetComponent<Button>().text`.

To convert single character to `string` create a `string` like this

`string tem=Character.toString(your_character)` (string containing single space), voila

Now use it.

Comment: I can't split the word "abandon" one by one like "a" ,"b" and so on. that's actually what I wanted

Comment: I have added that too

Comment: I've tried ```for(int i = 0; i < textArray[rowsToReadFrom[0]].Length; i++)
        {
           string s = textArray[rowsToReadFrom[0]].ToString();

            Debug.Log(s + "\n");
        }``` but it displays only 6 abandon word

Comment: why use a new `array` when you can directly access from the `string`, use it only if you need it more and more.

Comment: Now just concatenate `string` and access `char` directly, to handle exception you can use character to string converter , one I have mentioned in the edited answer.

Comment: I guess there's something wrong with the tem[0] sir

Comment: property or indexer 'string.this[int]' couldn't be assigned

Comment: Use `Character.toString()`

Comment: Apologies, `string` are immutable

Answer (score 0):

Though the answer there is correct also but I have my own answer and here it is

```
string temp = textArray[rowsToReadFrom[0]];
temp = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(temp, @"\s", "");
char[] chArr = temp.ToCharArray();
```

Then put it on a button like this

```
foreach (char c in chArr)
        {
            testObject clone = Instantiate(prefab.gameObject).GetComponent<testObject>();
            clone.transform.SetParent(container);

            charObjects.Add(clone.Init(c));

            //Debug.Log(c);
        }
```